# Truncated Poisson vs ordered multionomial + beta regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, beta-regression

I want to model a random variable that takes values between 0 and 1, and where 0 and 1 are included. Zero and one are possible values of the random variable and occur frequently. I have several covariates available

I think I have (at least) two options:

(a) Use an ordered logit for which part of the interval we are in: (1) 0, (2) the interval (0,1) and (3) the point 1. Afterwards I  can use a beta regression model for part (2).

(b) Discretize the interval [0,1] into say 10 equally spaced "intervals" 0,(0,0.1),[0.1,0.2),[0.2,0.3),[0.3,0.4),[0.5,0.6),[0.6,0.7),[0.7,0.8),[0.8,0.9),[0.9,1) 1 and use truncated Poisson, where I truncate at value 10.

Do you see any other options? What do you think about the options?

Comment: Maybe [fractional regression](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-08-20-fractional-regression/) would be an option?

Comment: seems like a great solution. Supernice that one can used already existing software!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (a) you also see practitioners using a multinomial logit (rather than ordered logit) for the first step.

In (b) you would typically censor the distribution rather than truncate it. Also, I wouldn't use a distribution for discrete data but a distribution for continuous data, e.g., a normal distribution (censored at both 0 and 1).

Additionally, there are other similar extensions like the "ordered beta regression" proposed by Robert Kubinec in *Political Analysis*, see: [doi:10.1017/pan.2022.20](https://doi.org/10.1017/pan.2022.20).

Comment: Thanks for yout answer! How would you estimate these models? Why censoring instead of truncation?

Answer (score 0):

As @achim wrote, my model, available in the R package ordbetareg, implements your (a) option using a Bayesian regression model, except that both distributions are fit jointly. You can see the package vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordbetareg/vignettes/package_introduction.html.